# Count Alternative For Huge Databases

Tags: mysql, count

**EDIT: Count seems to not work no matter what I do. I was thinking of a different way of counting where I use some kind of SQL query that would re-compile all of the rows id's.**

**What I mean?
Example Database:**

```
ID - First Name
----------------
1 - John
3 - Joe
4 - Sal
9 - Murry
```

**See it skips 2,5,6,7,8 because those rows were deleted. Is it possible to reset all current rows ids and auto increment them? If so then I could just do: `SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` and that should take like a few seconds and if I dont delete any records it should be pretty precise too.**

---

`Count(*)` is being so slow on my Database with about 800'000 rows.

Almost all the time I can't even load the page.
Is there any faster alternative? `Count(1)` makes no difference.

This is my PHP:

This is the countrows function:

```
//Create a new function named query;
function countrows($sql = false,$dbname = false,$obj = false) {

    //Prepare The SQL Query;
    $query = Connect('localhost','shinymk_admin','password',$dbname)->prepare($sql);

    $res = true;

    //Execute Binded Query;
    try { $query->execute(); $count = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); }

    catch (PDOException $e) {

        $count = false;

    }

    //If no errors happened Make $row true;
    return $count[0];

}
```

Comment: Count using the table index(es) as that should be much faster.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No idea what you mean, May you link me a tutorial?

Comment: Let's say the table is indexed on a column called `id`. You should use `COUNT(id)`

Comment: Oh right thats what you mean @JayBlanchard kk, One sec ill give it a shot.

Comment: Do you have proper indexes on the table, and did you tried to count over indexed columns ?

Comment: Still seems to be extremely slow, Im assuming at this point my only option is to store the count in a file or something :/

Comment: @CihanUygun Yes, My ID column is Indexed.

Comment: Are you counting with a WHERE clause, or similar? Show your query, show any tables involved, and any indexes on those tables

Comment: @MarkBaker I dont use any Wheres, Not needed, Query is literally just SELECT count(id) FROM tablename, the table has about 5 columns and only ID is indexed.

Comment: Ill update my Question with what im using.

Comment: We don't need to see the PHP code, you need to post the table schema and the SQL.

Comment: @Barmar well idk but Iupdated my question with a step I could take but unsure if its possible.

Comment: select count(your-primary-key) will be the best solution - look no other way. waste time

Answer (score 3):

The truth of the matter is that

```
  COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM table
```

is the fastest way to get an accurate row count. If, on the other hand, you use

```
 COUNT(some_column) AS rowcount FROM table
```

it will count the number of rows with a non-NULL column value. That can, but doesn't have to be, stupid full-table-scan slow.

If you happen to be using the MyISAM access method, `COUNT(*)` should be very fast, because that access method keeps track of counts.  If you're using InnoDB, it won't be quite as fast.  But 800K records isn't really very many.

You may benefit from doing

```
 OPTIMIZE TABLE table
```

in this case where `COUNT(*)` is very slow.